# Separate link structure for specific posts (/blog/glossary in stead of just /blog)

Tags: permalinks

I would like to create the following link structure:

my.domain.com/blog/'postname': this is the standard structure for blog posts
my.domain.com/blog/glossary/'postname': this is a separate structure for specific posts

'blog' is the main category for both types of posts and 'glossary' could be a second category or a tag (whichever works best for what I'm trying to accomplish).

How can this be done?

Thanks!

Comment: Create a separate [custom post type](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/post-types/) called "glossary" and set `with_front` to `true`.

Comment: Thank you. Isn't true the default setting for with_front?

Answer (score 1):

I just found out that what I want can be easily accomplished by creating a category 'glossary' which is a subcategory for 'blog'.

Answer (score -2):

You can try using [Custom Permalinks](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-permalinks/). It enables you to assign custom permalinks for specific posts. Follow these steps:

1. Install and activate Custom Permalink.
2. Go to the post where you want to use custom permalink.
3. In the Permalink field, type in your custom URL. You can even
   include the "/" character to replicate a folder structure.[image]
4. Finally, save the changes.